# Почему в Andorid в элементе spinner пропадает стрелка?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

У меня есть объект Spinner (выпадающий список). На моем устройстве (samsung a5) и на эмуляторах все в порядке , но на Samsung s10+ пропадает стрелочка: 
[image: s 10+]

[image: a 5]

Comment: Вероятно это особенность либо конкретной оболочки либо возможно 9 андроида. Попробуйте сделать кастомный спиннер